# How to change ggplot2 lineplot color based on y value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 in R to create a lineplot. The y value of the line is rates and the x value is dates. I want the color of the line to change depending on what the rates value is, so I wrote a for loop to assign the variable color based on what the rates is (i.e. >90 = Blue, <70 = Red).

The dataset looks like this:

| dates | rates | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | 91 | Blue |
| 1/2/21 | 42 | Red |
| 1/3/21 | NA | NA |

etc.

The code looks like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=dates,y=rates)) +
 geom_line(aes(color = color)) +
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y",date_breaks = "1 week") +
 labs(title = "Title", x = "Date", y = "Rates (%)")
```

For some reason, it keeps plotting like this:
[image: line_plot]

I want it to look like this, but with colors:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing `dates` to date class, specifying `group = 1` in `aes` and use `scale_color_identity` to get the same color as the name in `color` column of the dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(dates = lubridate::mdy(dates)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=dates,y=rates, color = color, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_identity() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y",date_breaks = "1 week") +
  labs(title = "Title", x = "Date", y = "Rates (%)")
```

Comment: How do I get the legend to show up?

Comment: "group = 1" for the win.